# Errors in Android Studio, works on device

Tags: android, android-studio

I've got a weird issue with Android Studio. A number of import statements like

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
```

They fail on the gcm and loopj parts. Yet if I build and run the project it works fine.
I've including them into my build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0', 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36')
compile files('/libs/android-async-http-1.4.3.jar', '/libs/CWAC-SackOfViewsAdapter.jar')
```

}

Anyone have any idea why I'm getting the errors in the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a new project, and pasted in my files, and it worked fine. I guess this is a the problem with using software in beta :P.